# Unity: Post Request unable to connect to destination host

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, post, networking

I'm familiar with Unity but new to trying to communicate with servers. I'm trying to set up a login screen but I'm having troubling Posting to the server properly. The strange part is the Get is working fine, but the Post turns up the following Error :

```
Cannot connect to destination host Network
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
LoginHandler:CheckForNetworkErrors(UnityWebRequest) (at 
Assets/Scripts/LoginHandler.cs:120)
<LoginUser>c__Iterator2:MoveNext() (at Assets/Scripts/LoginHandler.cs:92)
.UnityEngine.SetupCoroutine:InvokeMoveNext(IEnumerator, IntPtr)
```

I'm using a test URL to make sure it was't an issue with the original. Both return the same error. The following code is sent once the player hits a login button. Any ideas on what im doing wrong here?

```
public IEnumerator LoginUser()
{
    string testURL = "https://www.google.com/";

    using (UnityWebRequest get = UnityWebRequest.Get(testURL))
    {
        yield return get.Send();

        ParseCSRF(get.downloadHandler.text);

        CheckForNetworkErrors(get);

    }

    WWWForm form = new WWWForm();
    form.AddField("username", username.text);
    form.AddField("password", password.text);
    form.AddField("_csrf", csrf);

    using (UnityWebRequest post = UnityWebRequest.Post(WWW.EscapeURL(testURL), form))
    {
        yield return post.SendWebRequest();

        CheckForNetworkErrors(post);
    }

}

public void CheckForNetworkErrors(UnityWebRequest www)
{
    if(www.isNetworkError) 
    {
        Debug.Log(www.error + " Network");
    }
    else if (www.isHttpError)
    {
        Debug.Log(www.error + " http");

    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log("Form upload complete!" + www.downloadHandler.text);
    }
}
```

Comment: is your destination host google? Can you ping your host? are you sure that do you have access to your server? Sometimes the code can be ok, but some configuration on the servers (like, the ports are not open, firewalls, etc.) can be the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I have tested with the code I wrote below:

```
 void Start()
{
    StartCoroutine(GetCrt());
}

IEnumerator GetCrt()
{
    string testURL = "https://www.google.com/";

    using (UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Get(testURL))
    {
        yield return www.SendWebRequest();

        if (www.isNetworkError || www.isHttpError)
        {
            Debug.Log(www.error);
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("Get Request Completed!");
        }
    }
}
```

It's working fine.

For the post request you need a real form data, you can't send a post request to google.com.

Hope this help you.

Happy Coding!

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the response! The Post is whats giving me issues, even when i supply the correct URL it still has trouble connecting to the destination host. Any ideas on what could cause that?